# Is there a way to access arguments stored in the function object returned by std::bind() in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, std, stdbind

I need a way to decompose the function object returned by `std::bind()` to its arguments in a function template.

The code snippet below shows what I'd like to do:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

void foo(int x, double y, char z)
{
    std::cout << "x = " << x << ", y = " << y << ", z = " << z << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    auto f = std::bind(foo, 42, 3.14, 'a');
    std::cout << "The first argument is: " << std::get<0>(f) << '\n';
    std::cout << "The second argument is: " << std::get<1>(f) << '\n';
    std::cout << "The third argument is: " << std::get<2>(f) << '\n';
}
```

The output should be:

```bash
The first argument is: 42
The second argument is: 3.14
The third argument is: a
```

But it doesn't compile with the error:

```bash
test.cpp:12:60: error: no matching function for call to ‘get<0>(std::_Bind<void (*(int, double, char))(int, double, char)>&)’
```

**Why do I need this?**

`std::generate()` and `std::generate_n()` can accept both an engine or a distribution to generate random numbers. When you pass a distribution, a standard way is `std::bind` in addition to functors and lambdas:

```
std::mt19937 R(666);
std::::uniform_int_distribution<int> D(0, 100);
std::vector<int> v(10);
std::generate(v.begin(), v.end(), std::bind(D, std::ref(R));
```

I've developed a parallel `generate()` algorithm that plays fair (i.e. you always get the same sequence if you use the same seed and distribution). I'd like it to have the same interface as `std::generate()` but the algorithm requires a call to the `discard()` function of the engine, which is unnecessary for the serial algorithm. My idea is to use `std::is_bind_expression<T>::value` to see if an engine or a distribution is passed. If it's an engine, call `discard()` and if it's a bind expression, first decompose it and then call `discard()` on the engine. Lambdas are not going to work here because the algorithm can't access the engine.
If it's not possible with the `std::bind` implementation, then I'll implement my version of `std::bind`.

If there's a  better way to do this, I'll be more than glad to know it.

Comment: Interesting question, but _why_ do you need this? The returned object is not meant to be depickled so if you really need that, it feels like something is wrong with the design.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I've added a **Why do I need this?** section to my question.

Comment: _"both an engine **or** a distribution to generate random numbers"_ - No, it doesn't accept a distribution.. The signature of the functor should be `R()` which doesn't match that of distributions, which takes a generator as a parameter. _"When you pass a distribution, a standard way is `std::bind` ..."_ - Well, then it's not a distribution anymore. It's then just a regular generator. _"to see if an engine or a distribution is passed"_ - A distribution is _never_ passed to `generate`. Why not use the standard tags `std::execution::par` etc. for your version of `generate`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not possible.

[`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) returns an unspecified type with only the following guaranteed:

- a copy or move constructor;
- (deprecated) `result_type` type alias;
- `operator()`.

If you need the feature described in your question, you must come up with your own definition of `bind`.

Answer (score 4):

`std::bind` can be considered deprecated and is replaced by lambdas. I heard about cases where `std::bind` is still needed, but I never met them.

You can write your custom function wrapper that stores the arguments in a tuple.

```
#include <functional>
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

template <typename R,typename BoundTuple,typename ... Args>
struct my_function {
    BoundTuple bound;
    std::function<R(Args...)> func;
    template <typename...MoreArgs>
    R operator()(MoreArgs&& ... more) {
        return std::apply(func,std::tuple_cat(bound,std::tuple(more...)));
    }
};

template <typename R,typename ... Bound,typename ... Args>
my_function<R,std::tuple<Bound...>,Args...> my_bind(std::function<R(Args...)>&& f,Bound&&...b){
    return {{b...},f};
}

void foo(int x, double y, char z) {
    std::cout << "x = " << x << ", y = " << y << ", z = " << z << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    auto f = my_bind(std::function(foo), 42, 3.14, 'a');
    std::cout << "The first argument is: " << std::get<0>(f.bound) << '\n';
    std::cout << "The second argument is: " << std::get<1>(f.bound) << '\n';
    std::cout << "The third argument is: " << std::get<2>(f.bound) << '\n';
    f();
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qE1E7EW9x)

However, take this with a grain of salt. Refernces are not handled and only arguments starting from left can be bound. Its just to illustrate the approach. Whether this approach can be extended to fir your needs depends on details.

In my humble opinion the interface of [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) is terrible (e.g "If some of the arguments that are supplied in the call to g() are not matched by any placeholders stored in g, the unused arguments are evaluated and discarded." yikes!), which can be taken as evidence that it is not trivial to get it right.

Comment: Then how to handle place_holder? :-)

Comment: @Jarod42 much more is missing (eg references). I added some comment to the answer to make it more clear that the code is just a toy example to illustrate the approach.

Comment: @ArminSobhani: you have the tuple as argument, just handle `std::reference_wrapper`...

Comment: Was not my code BTW ;-)

Comment: @ArminSobhani editing the question after you received answers is problematic because usually it invalidates already posted answers. When I said "reference are not handled" i actually meant that the caller has to take care of them  (by using `std::reference_wrapper`) while in a full blown implementation I'd expect that the `bind` function handles them automatically. On the other hand, compare to what eg `std::thread` does, there is was considered to let the caller explicitly use a ref wrapper. So, again, it really depends on details.

Comment: @ArminSobhani the issue with editing the quesiton afterwards is that "If there's a better way to do this" and "can I access the arguments bound by std::bind?" are really two different questions. The answers you got refer to the latter while the first most likely will not use `std::bind`. Imho it would be better to move the part about the random engine to a new question. From there you can link to this one with a comment along the line of "I know std::bind cannot do it [link to this question]. What can I do instead?"

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai +1 for the custom version implemented with a tuple.